# Javascript: What is the easiest way to place the same item in an array more than once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a Javascript beginner (more or less).

I've created a new array:

```
var genres = [
    "metal",
    "rockroll",
    "funk",
    "punk",
    "country",
];
```

However, I'd like to put each genre in the array a specific number of times, not just once. I know I can just repeat each line as many times as I need, but I'm sure there's a better way.

It would be great if I could do something like this:

```
var genres = [
    "metal" * 3,
    "rockroll" * 5,
    "funk" * 1,
    "punk" * 0,
    "country" * 4,
];
```

...but of course I've tried that, and it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out? I wasn't able to find anything by googling.

Thanks!

Comment: `"punk" * 0`, but why? You could just omit this line.

Comment: First thought, and I'm on mobile so I can't post a complete answer: `Array.flat(new Array(3).fill('metal')…)`? Using [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Obj/Array/flat).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir perhaps the number is determined at runtime

Comment: Yup, it's something that will vary. Sometimes I'll have many of a genre, sometimes few, sometimes none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build an array like this with `reduce()` if you start with some data structure that holds your counts and categories:

```js
let cats = [[3, "metal"], [5, "rockroll"], [1, "funk"], [0, "punk"], [4, "country"] ]
 // etc..
let arr = cats.reduce((arr, [n, cat]) => arr.concat(Array(n).fill(cat)), [])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: FWIW: this usage of `reduce` is also called a "flat map", there is a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) supported in some contexts, which is not-yet-standard .. unfortunately. Regardless, the link shows equivalency.

Comment: …and I for one @user2864740 can't wait until `Array.prototype.flatMap()` is more widely available!

Comment: Me too :) It's such a useful - and undervalued outside of 'functional langauges' - function.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it'll be easiest for me to use in the long run. (But that's just a guess.)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let item = [
  {
    genres: "metal",
    count: 3
  },
  {
    genres: "rockroll",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    genres: "funk",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    genres: "punk",
    count: 0
  }
];

console.log(item);
item.map(i => {
  for(let n = 0; n < i.count; n++){
    console.log(i.genres);
  }
});
```

How do you think about using the `Object`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you could easily write a function to do it.  For instance:

```
function addMultiples (input) {
    const output = []
    for (let key in input) {
        for (let i = 0; i < input[key]; i++) {
            output.push(key)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

Then you would pass in your values as an object:

```
console.log(addMultiples({
    "metal": 3,
    "rockroll": 5,
    "funk": 1,
    "punk": 0,
    "country": 4
}).join(", "))
// prints "metal, metal, metal, rockroll, rockroll, rockroll, rockroll, rockroll, funk, country, country, country, country"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and keep your sub arrays filled. And only spread them when needed:

```js
let cats = [[3, "metal"], [5, "rockroll"], [1, "funk"], [0, "punk"], [4, "country"]]

const filled = Array.from(cats, ([v,k]) => new Array(v).fill(k)) // fill arrays

console.log(filled.reduce((r,c) => [...r, ...c]))  // spread for output
```